# Adv Filter: Extracted range has missing or illegal field name

Tags: excel, vba

When doing a adv filter its telling the The extract range has missing or illegal field name.

I had tried changing the macro to another module and when doing adv manually its working

Please help me in this matter.

```
Sub gp()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim Reco As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("As per Books")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("As per Govt Portal")
Set Reco = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reco")
Dim rgdataGp As Range, rgcriteriaGp As Range, rgoutputGp As Range

Dim LastRow As Long

With Reco
   LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set rgdataGp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("As Per govt portal").Range("A7").CurrentRegion
Set rgcriteriaGp = Reco.Range("M1").CurrentRegion
Set rgoutputGp = Reco.Range("A" & LastRow).CurrentRegion

rgdataGp.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgcriteriaGp, rgoutputGp
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reco").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearFormats
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Once You put `As per Govt Portal` and next time `As Per govt portal`.
Btw which line error appeared?

Comment: Check the address of `rgoutputGp`. Does every cell in the first row of that range have a header that matches a column in the source data?

Comment: The most common way for this error to appear is if the headers of the range you're copying from, don't match the headers of the range you're copying to. All headers must match exactly, if not this error appears.

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=QflOfD this is a sample file please check and adive me

Comment: `rgdataGp.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgcriteriaGp, rgoutputGp` here i got the error